# No Sound Coming From Android Emulator | Android Studio

Tags: java, android

```
MediaPlayer player;

// Playing Sound
    public void playSound(View v){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
                Log.e("start","player çalıştı");
            }
        });
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.release();
                Log.e("stop", "player durdu");
            }
        });
    }
```

My code is here and with this code i do not get any sound from physical and virtual device.

Comment: Do you happen to use Bluetooth headphones? I was experiencing problems using them with the android emulator.

Comment: @Samet Yilmaz - What is the operating system?